# How to fix RuntimeBinderException when using dynamicJsonObject.getDynamicMemberNames()

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, nullreferenceexception

**I have found the solution to this question while writing it, but I'm still posting it so that if somebody has this problem in the future, they can find this**

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56846107/add-dynamic-elements-to-an-already-existing-model-in-net-mvc) as in this is my latest attempt at solving my issue.

In short :

in my .Net MVC Project, I receive a Json with some unpredictable data (an array of :). I can decode this Json using

```
dynamic dynamicObj =System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(await someAPIcall(someParameters));
```

And i can explore the data by mousing over it in VisualStudio (although it is a much more complex structure as the json that is sent) and also the ObjectDumper nuget is able to display all the properties.

Now, how can i access this data in my code ?

I've tried the following :

Acessing the properties as with any object by chaining property names like :

```
dynamicObj._values[1].Key
```

which, following the path in the mouse over data explorer (don't know the name of it), should give me a simple string. But I get this error :

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform 
runtime binding on a null reference
```

So I tried to see if maybe the name was somehow different in this object, so i tried :

```
foreach (string name in dynamicObj.getDynamicMemberNames())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Which is a method of the [DynamicJsonObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.dynamicjsonobject.getdynamicmembernames?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#System_Web_Helpers_DynamicJsonObject_GetDynamicMemberNames) but this raises this error :

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform 
runtime binding on a null reference
```

when clearly dynamicObj is not null.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that this line :

```
dynamic dynamicObj = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(await 
someAPIcall(someParameters)));
```

which should be this :

```
DynamicJsonObject dynamicObj = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(await 
someAPIcall(someParameters));
```